# filter object by being used in other query

Tags: django, django-models

I am having two models. `Procedures` and `ProcedureCategories`. Now every `Procedure` can have a foreignkey to a `ProcedureCategory`.

I want to do two things: Get all `Procedures` of a specific type for my usergroup. And get all categories that are used in these `Procedures`.

Here are my models:

```
class ProcedureCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        help_text="Enter category name."
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.name < other.name

class Procedure(models.Model):
    """Model representing a task (but not a specific copy of a procedure)."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(ProcedureTypes, help_text="Select a type for this procedure")
    summary = RichTextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the task", blank=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, help_text="Select which groups should be assigned for the task", blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProcedureCategories, on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text="Select which category should be assigned for the task", blank=True, null=True)
    date_done = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.title
```

The first thing is easy:

```
procedureModels = Procedure.objects.filter(type=2, groups__user=request.user)
```

This gives me all `Procedures` of type 2 with correct user group.

But how can I get all `ProcedureCategorires` that are used in these `Procedures`?

```
ProcedureCategories.filter()?
```

I would probably need to join it somehow. How can I do this in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the `ForeignKey` in reverse:

```
categories = ProcedureCategories.objects.filter(
    procedure__type=2, procedure__groups__user=request.user
)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `ProcedureCategory` instead of <s>`ProcedureCategories`</s>.

Comment: Thanks! How can I prevent having duplicates? Because this gives me the same categories multiple times. Do I need to group by category?

Comment: @progNewbie: no, you add `.distinct()` at the end of the queryset.